# android singleLine vs maxLines

Tags: android, android-layout

I thought `singleLine="true"` was equivalent to `maxLines="1"` but I see that the following pre-populated field from Android Studio has both. Is there a difference? Is there a known bug that causes both to be required?

```
<EditTextPreference
   android:key="example_text"
   android:title="@string/pref_title_display_name"
   android:defaultValue="@string/pref_default_display_name"
   android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
   android:inputType="textCapWords"
   android:capitalize="words"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:maxLines="1" />
```

this is from the `pref_general.xml` file.

Comment: Maybe related? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17125324/2095855

Comment: Doesn't it have something to do with being able to add new lines with the keyboard? I'm pretty sure singleLine="true" blocks it from making another line.

Comment: As far as I know and atleast in the new version of Android Studio, the preferences XML file is done manually. So, I was wondering how did Android Studio pre-populate it when you do that yourself.

Answer (score 16):

From Android website:

**[singleLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine):**

> Constrains the text to a single horizontally scrolling line instead of
>   letting it wrap onto multiple lines, and advances focus instead of
>   inserting a newline when you press the enter key. The default value is
>   false (multi-line wrapped text mode) for non-editable text, but if you
>   specify any value for inputType, the default is true (single-line
>   input field mode).
>
> Must be a boolean value, either "true" or "false".

**[maxLines](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#maxLines):**

> Makes the TextView be at most this many lines tall. When used on an
>   editable text, the inputType attribute's value must be combined with
>   the textMultiLine flag for the maxLines attribute to apply.
>
> Must be an integer value, such as "100"

Please note that singleLine has been deprecated since API 3 and maxLines should be used instead. So all you need really is

```
android:maxLines = integer // 1 for single line or add lines multiple as well.
```

Comment: Is `singleLine` really deprecated? I found no warnings in the visual preview of AS. In my case `singleLine=true` and `maxLines=1` give different results.

Comment: singleLine does not appear to be deprecated. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine

Comment: It is now, but for EditTexts, `singleLine` should still be used because `maxLines` will not wrap carriage returns.

Comment: `maxLines=1` doesn't prevent user input linebreaks, but `singleLine` does. It doesn't make sense to use `maxLines` instead.

Comment: you can use `android:lines` instead. same behaviour like `android:maxLines`

Comment: @mochadwi android:lines doesn't work with ellipsizing for me.

Comment: singleLine set to true causes maxLength to be ignored.

Comment: The one difference I saw between `android:lines` and `singleLine` is when the content is longer than screen size, in singleLine the content ends with `...` .

Answer (score 0):

**maxLines**

In EditText, `maxLines` property set with the particular value like 5 then 
only five line text is visible in EditText as well as the Enter key in
keypad also visible for Entering.

**singleLine**

In EditText, `singleLine` property is set with true value then only one line
text is int EditText visible as well as the Enter key in keypad not 
visible for Entering to us.

Thanks