# Jetpack Compose SingleLine Input Text

Tags: android, kotlin, textfield, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to set singleLine or maxLines on TextField?

I've checked a source and it's missing. Any ideas / workarounds?

Answer (score 22):

You can use the parameter **`maxLines`** or **`singleLine`**:

```
TextField(
    //..
    maxLines = 1)
```

or

```
TextField(
    //..
    singleLine = true)
```

Comment: Is there any difference between those two? To me it looks like `singleLine` is redundant.

Comment: I assuming the difference in Compose is the same as that of xml. See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879471/android-singleline-vs-maxlines

Comment: The documentation states that when `singleLine` is set to `true`, `maxLines` will automatically be set to `1`. However, neither setting stops the input to accept line breaks (e.g. from an external or keyboard that does not honor the `imeAction`).

Comment: There is a difference between singleLine and maxLines=1. `singleLine = true` forces text to be scrollable. Max lines is not.

Comment: Additionally if you set maxLines=1 you still can write a new line sign by clicking 'enter' on e.x. Gboard. But if you instead  set singleLine = true - 'enter' key would close the keyboard and doen't affect the text.

Answer (score 8):

Since [Compose 1.0.0-alpha08](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material#1.0.0-alpha08), you can use `singleLine` parameter to make the text field a single horizontally scrollable line:

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { },
    singleLine = true
)
```

Answer (score -2):

I can't see any property which can do it directly.
One work around could be:

```
TextField(
    value = yourText,
    onValueChange = { s: TextFieldValue ->
        if (s.text.count { it == '\n' } < 3) { // 3 lines (or two enters)
            yourText = s
        }
    }
)
```