# PasswordVisualTransformation converts enter key to asterisk

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am implementing a `PasswordInput` composable using Jetpack compose, which is [literally one of the examples](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#formatting) provided by the Android developers website:

```
@Composable
fun PasswordInput() {
    var password by remember { mutableStateOf("admin") }

    TextField(
        value = password,
        onValueChange = { password = it },
        label = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.prompt_password)) },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password)
    )
}
```

Here I default my password to "admin", which is five characters long. It shows five asterisks.

[image: lol]

But if a user presses the enter key there, the password field becomes six characters long.

[image: more lol]

Questions:

1. Why does it do that?
2. How can it be modified to not do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my question. It needs `singleLine = true`, which the docs did not mention.

Fixed code:

```
@Composable
fun PasswordInput() {
    var password by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

    TextField(
        value = password,
        onValueChange = { password = it },
        maxLines = 1,
        singleLine = true,
        label = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.prompt_password)) },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password)
    )
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65121116/1558430)