# Why are words that go outside a single line TextView's bounds not rendered and clipped?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-animation

I have a `TextView` enclosed in a container like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Hi World" />

</FrameLayout>
```

A width on the `FrameLayout` of 40 dp is not quite enough to enclose the full line of text. I would therefore expect the `TextView` to be clipped by its parent. Instead, the `TextView` does not render the word "World" at all!

| Expected | Actual |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Expected - Text is clipped] | [image: Actual - Second word not rendered] |

1. Why is the second word not rendered?
2. How can I get the `TextView` to be clipped instead? This is part of a width changing animation (container resized to 0dp width) where removing letters or *chunks* of text causes annoying flickering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as you expected

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="none"

        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Hi World" />
```

Also this

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"

        android:inputType="text"

        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Hi World" />
```

[image]

Comment: I thought `singleLine` was deprecated but perhaps that only applies to `EditText`s (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879471/android-singleline-vs-maxlines). Will try this tomorrow. I'm a bit hesitant to using `inputType` as the docs clearly state that "Setting this attribute to anything besides none also implies that the text is editable".

Comment: Since is a TextView and not an EditText it doesn't apply

Comment: Tested and it works. AS does mark `singleLine` as deprecated in the suggestion box but not once it is written out.